# Abstracting over Math Operations in an Interpreter in Java

Tags: java, interpreter, abstraction

I'm writing an AST Interpreter in Java have quite a few methods that check the argument types and perform a operation if they match. By now there are more than five methods that are basically copy pasted versions of each other. Is there a way to abstract the types to check and the operation to perform?

```java
    @Override
    public Object visitMultiplyNode(MultiplyNode multiplyNode) {
        Object lhs = multiplyNode.getLeftHandSide().accept(this);
        Object rhs = multiplyNode.getRightHandSide().accept(this);

        if (lhs instanceof Double && rhs instanceof Double) {
            return (double) lhs * (double) rhs;
        }
        if (lhs instanceof Long && rhs instanceof Long) {
            return (long) lhs * (long) rhs;
        }
        throw new TypeError("Can not multiply " + lhs.getClass() + " and " + rhs.getClass() + ".");
    }
```

The types I want to check aren't always to same, for example the modulus node only accepts Longs and the addition node also accepts Strings for concatenation.

```java
    @Override
    public Object visitAddNode(AddNode addNode) {
        Object lhs = addNode.getLeftHandSide().accept(this);
        Object rhs = addNode.getRightHandSide().accept(this);

        if (lhs instanceof Double && rhs instanceof Double) {
            return (double) lhs + (double) rhs;
        }
        if (lhs instanceof Long && rhs instanceof  Long) {
            return (long) lhs + (long) rhs;
        }
        if (lhs instanceof String && rhs instanceof String) {
            return "" + lhs + lhs;
        }
        throw new TypeError("Can not add " + lhs.getClass() + " and " + rhs.getClass() + ".");
    }

    @Override
    public Object visitModulusNode(ModulusNode modulusNode) {
        Object lhs = modulusNode.getLeftHandSide().accept(this);
        Object rhs = modulusNode.getRightHandSide().accept(this);

        if (lhs instanceof Long && rhs instanceof Long) {
            return (long) lhs % (long) rhs;
        }
        throw new TypeError("Can not take modulus of " + lhs.getClass() + " and " + rhs.getClass() + ".");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a lambda:

```
private Object visitBinaryOperatorNode(BinaryOpNode node, BiFunction<T, T> op) {
    Object lhs = node.getLeftHandSide().accept(this);
    Object rhs = node.getRightHandSide().accept(this);

    if (lhs instanceof Long && rhs instanceof Long) {
        return op.apply((long) lhs, (long) rhs);
    }
    throw new TypeError("Can not take " + node.getOpName() + "of " + lhs.getClass() + " and " + rhs.getClass() + ".");
}
```

However, since you support multiple types for some of your operators, you need another layer of abstraction:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor// Lombok, otherwise write the boilerplate yourself
public class BinaryOperator<T, T> {
   @NonNull private final BiFunction<T, T> op;
   @NonNull private final Class<T> clazz;

   public boolean isApplicable(Object left, Object right) {
       return clazz.isInstance(left) && clazz.isInstance(right);
   }

   public T apply(Object left, Object right) {
       return op.apply(clazz.cast(left), clazz.cast(right));
   }
}
```

You can now pass a bunch of valid binary operators and test if they're applicable, and if so, apply them.

```
private static final List<BinaryOperator<?, ?>> VALID_ADD_OPERATORS = Arrays.asList(
    new BinaryOperator<>((x, y) -> x + y, Double.class), 
    new BinaryOperator<>((x, y) -> x + y, Long.class),
    new BinaryOperator<>((x, y) -> x + y, String.class)
);

private static final List<BinaryOperator<?, ?>> VALID_MULTIPLY_OPERATORS = Arrays.asList(
    new BinaryOperator<>((x, y) -> x * y, Double.class), 
    new BinaryOperator<>((x, y) -> x * y, Long.class)
);

@Override
public Object visitAddNode(AddNode addNode) {
    return visitBinaryOperatorNode(addNode, VALID_ADD_OPERATORS );
}

@Override
public Object visitMultiplyNode(MultiplyNode multiplyNode) { 
    return visitBinaryOperatorNode(multiplyNode, VALID_MULTIPLY_OPERATORS ); 
}

private Object visitBinaryOperatorNode(BinaryOpNode node, List<BinaryOperator<?, ?>> validOperators) {
    Object lhs = node.getLeftHandSide().accept(this);
    Object rhs = node.getRightHandSide().accept(this);

    for (BinaryOperator<?, ?> op : validOperators) {
        if (op.isApplicable(lhs, rhs)) return op.apply(lhs, rhs);
    }
    throw new TypeError("Can not take " + node.getOpName() + "of " + lhs.getClass() + " and " + rhs.getClass() + ".");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could extract these checks into individual objects and reuse it when needed.
For example by defining an enum value for each type that you want to handle to convert.

For example

```
public enum ConvertType {

    DOUBLE {
        Object apply(Object lhs, Object rhs) {
            if (lhs instanceof Double && rhs instanceof Double) {
                return (double) lhs + (double) rhs;
            }
            return null;
        }
    },

    LONG {
        Object apply(Object lhs, Object rhs) {
            if (lhs instanceof Long && rhs instanceof Long) {
                return (long) lhs + (long) rhs;
            }
            return null;
        }
    },

    STRING {
        Object apply(Object lhs, Object rhs) {
            if (lhs instanceof String && rhs instanceof String) {
                return "" + lhs + lhs;
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    public static Object apply(Object a, Object b, ConvertType... convertTypes) {
        for (ConvertType convertType : convertTypes) {
            Object result = convertType.apply(a, b);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        throw new TypeError("Can not take modulus of " + a.getClass() + " and " + b.getClass() + ".");

    }

}
```

The entry point to convert would be the static method :

```
public static Object apply(Object a, Object b, ConvertType... convertTypes)
```

that allows to pass `ConvertType`s as you want with a variable number thanks to the `var-args`.

For example :

```
@Override
public Object visitMultiplyNode(MultiplyNode multiplyNode) {
    Object lhs = multiplyNode.getLeftHandSide().accept(this);
    Object rhs = multiplyNode.getRightHandSide().accept(this);        
    return ConvertType.apply(lhs , rhs, ConvertType.DOUBLE, ConvertType.LONG);
}
```

or :

```
@Override
public Object visitAddNode(AddNode addNode) {
    Object lhs = addNode.getLeftHandSide().accept(this);
    Object rhs = addNode.getRightHandSide().accept(this);
    return ConvertType.apply(lhs , rhs, ConvertType.DOUBLE, ConvertType.LONG, ConvertType.STRING);    
}
```